# argparse: Different outcome of script then with rawinput()

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hej Pebs,
I am fairly new to (Python) coding, so please formulate your answers for a DAU.

The purpose of my code is to scrape image links from my company's website and export them to a CSV.
For a first test, I defined the URL simply with raw_input() and it works as intended, but the images on the page are in different formats and the output may differ so I wanted to define all my search variables via argparse.

My problem is that the links list is now empty, when before (with raw_input) it contain exactly what I wanted.

I checked if the type for URL differed for raw_input or argparse, eventhough I defined it as a string, but it is a string for both times.

NOTE: I did not code the filter part yet.

```
#import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser("Add arguments to define links you want")
p.add_argument("-url","--url", type=str, help="Url you want the image links from", required='TRUE')
#p.add_argument("-p","--p", help="Type of image: l for landscape, p for portrait or s for square", choices=["l","p","s"], required=TRUE)
#p.add_argument("-f","--f", help="Number of frames per creative/ Frames in template", choices=["1","2","3"], required=TRUE)
#p.add_argument("-n","--n", help="Number of creatives", default="1")
args = p.parse_args()

#URL = requests.get(raw_input("Page you want image links from? ")).content
URL = args.url
print (type(URL))

soup = BeautifulSoup(URL, "lxml")
links=[]
for link in soup.find_all('figure', limit=10):                                                      
    for img in link.find_all('img'):                                                                
        if ".jpg" not in str(img):                                                                  
            continue                                                                               
        links.append(img.get('data-echo'))                                                          
print (links)
```

**EDIT**

The input is a catalogue page of our web shop without metacharacters eg: 
-url https://www.juniqe.de/tags/skandinavisches-design-wohnen

The expected output (as with rawInput) would be a list like this:
['https://rndr.juniqe.com/media/catalog/product/seo-cache/x386/383/13/383-13-101P/Mountain-The-Wall-Shop-Premium-Poster.jpg', 'url/to/second.jpg', etc]

The actual output is just []

Comment: So what's the URL you entered? Did you make sure to escape it to prevent the shell from interpreting metacharacters? Both `?`, `&` (often used in URL query parameters) have special meaning in a shell and *may not be passed to the program you are executing*. This is not a Python issue, that's how shells work.

Comment: Why was this question put on hold? It seems a perfectly legitimate question

Comment: @OferSadan: it needs expected input and expected output. It is not an MCVE at this point.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the clarification regarding the MCVE policy. Is it now a viable question?

Comment: Ah, I see it. You remove the `requests.get()` call. You are passing the URL to `BeautifulSoup`, it expects HTML, and a url is not HTML. Why did you remove the `requests` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changed more than just where the URL comes from. You also removed the code that *actually loads the HTML*:

```
#import requests
```

and

```
#URL = requests.get(raw_input("Page you want image links from? ")).content
```

The `requests.get()` call is the *crucial difference*; you are now passing the raw URL string to BeautifulSoup, and in that string is no HTML to parse.

Put back the code that loads the webpage, and perhaps use better variable names so you don't get confused between URL and HTML:

```
import requests

args = p.parse_args()
response = requests.get(args.url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation! I forgot that BeautifulSoup actually needs to load the HTML.

And thanks for the variable tip, will rework that.